# display the value of input id in another div

Tags: javascript

I want to display the value of `input id = "flotsam"` in `div id = "aux_fees"`. How can that be done?

I meant displaying the "title" of the expenditure. The website is https://verlager.com and the table has a column header with a default of "aux" I want that "aux" (an input field) to be typed over and then the TOTAL "AUX" at the top of the page displays the column title.

Maybe there is a better way. I should edit the AUX input directly and have the fixed string "aux" just remain as it is. I'll try that!

```
<div id="aux_fees"> AUX $ <input type="text" id="totalAux" disabled /></div>


<div class="AUX "><input onblur="displayResult()" placeholder = "aux" id = "flotsam" /></div>

<script>
function displayResult() {
    document.getElementById("aux_fees").innerHTML = "Have a nice day!";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('flotsam').value`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: in your `onblur()` pass the control as `displayResult(this)` then change the function definition to read the passed variable and set the value as `function displayResult(control){ document.getElementById("aux_fees").innerHTML = control.value;}`.

Comment: Displaying value in element with id `aux_fees` does not makes sense for me. Did you meant displaying value in disabled input with id `totalAux`?

Comment: No. I meant displaying the "title" of the expenditure. The website is https://verlager.com/ and the table has a column header with a default of  "aux" I want that "aux" (an input field) to be typed over and then the TOTAL "AUX" at the top of the page displays the column title.

Comment: So basically you need to show the sum in the disabled input box, right?

Comment: No, I already have the javacript computations for that. I just need to write the column input header ("aux") string in the table to the TOTAL AUX string.

Comment: Then the answer given below should work. Did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example - onblur only triggers when you move away from the textbox like tabbing for instance so you will need to type something and then press tab to get it to work.

```js
function displayResult() {
    document.getElementById("aux_fees").innerHTML =document.getElementById("flotsam").value;
}
```

```html
<div id="aux_fees"> AUX $ <input type="text" id="totalAux" disabled /></div>


<div class="AUX "><input onblur="displayResult()" placeholder="aux" id="flotsam" /></div>
```